# Code coverage when running e2e tests on a project with Angular 14 (TypeScript & ESM) + Playwright + Cucumber + nyc

Tags: playwright, cucumberjs, nyc

I cannot generate code coverage when I am running my e2e tests. It seems that there is no instrumentation done in this case.
I have created a sample app for which I am running one cucumber+playwright test but afterwards I get no coverage information. I have created an example here: https://github.com/testgitdl/playwright-coverage

and these are the scripts that I use to serve the app and run my tests:
`"scripts": { "ng": "ng", "serve": "ng serve", "build": "ng build", "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development", "test:only": "SET NODE_OPTIONS=--loader ts-node/esm --loader ./loader.js --no-warnings --experimental-specifier-resolution=node && node ./node_modules/@cucumber/cucumber/bin/cucumber.js --tags \"@fixMe\"", "test": "start-server-and-test serve http://localhost:4200 test:only", "test-with-coverage": "npx nyc --include './src/*.ts' --extension .ts --require ts-node/register --reporter=html --reporter=text --all npm run test" },`

The ./nyc_output is created but information without any coverage information. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: Unfortunatly no. Still trying